# Dimensions.get('window') seems off?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to get the dimensions of the screen using react native's `Dimensions` api. But it seems to be giving me the wrong dimensions on iOS. Are there any caveats to using `Dimensions.get('window').height/width`?

Comment: What values do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dimension with `const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');`.

Now you have two const `width` and `heigth`.